# Solutions of $x'' + 2x' + x = 0$ such that $x(1) = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve this question from an older exam that my teacher uploaded. The marks given for answering this question were very low, so I am thinking there is an easy way to solve it.
The question asks to find the solutions of $x'' + 2x' + x = 0$ such that $x(1) = 0$.
My approach is using the change $y=x'$, and therefore getting:
$$
x' = y
$$
$$
y' = -x -2y
$$
Which is a linear system. What I would normally do here is finding the eigenvalues (in this case there is only one eigenvalue, -1 with eigenvector (1,-1)), and solve the corresponding system using the Jordan matrix and the Jordan basis, but I was thinkin whether there was a faster approach, maybe playing with the fact that $x(1)=0$, or something else.

Thanks

Comment: You have a second order linear homogeneous ODE, so it suffices to find two linearly independent solutions. The usual method for such ODE's with constant coefficients is to look for solutions of the form $x(t)=e^{rt}$. But here we get that $r=-1$ is a double root of the characteristic equation, so by this method we only get one linearly independent solution. To obtain a second linearly independent solution, you multiply the first solution by $t$. For more information, see https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/de/RepeatedRoots.aspx.

Answer (score 2):

> To find the solutions of $x′′+2x′+x=0$ such that x(1)=0. My approach is using the change $y=x′$.

You can also choose $y=x'+x \implies y'+y=0$ or rewrite the DE as: $$(xe^t)''=0$$

Answer (score 1):

It is much too complicated, as this is a o.d.e. with constant coefficients. Its characteristic equation is $(\lambda+1)^2=0$.  As it has a double root, $\lambda=-1$, a basis of the space of solutions is made up of the functions $\mathrm e^{-t}$ and  $t\mathrm e^{-t}$. Therefore the general solution  is
$$x(t)=\mathrm e^{-t}(\alpha +\beta t),$$
and there remains to determine the relation between $\alpha$ and $\beta$ so that $x(0)=1$.

Comment: @projectilemotion: Right. I forgot to check my post. I actually changed the name of the variable while posting. I'll fix that within seconds. Thanks!